# Two dates formar from UI to Server (Java)

Tags: java, simpledateformat, dateformatter

Angualr UI is sending two dates format to server (Java). the communication is happened through JSON
UI Date values request :
String date1 ="2011-08-31T18:30:00Z";
String date2 ="Thu, 01 Sep 2011 00:00:00 GMT";

I used this approach on server side

System.out.println(Date.from(Instant.parse(date1)));
System.out.println(Date.from(Instant.parse(date2)));

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` if you can avoid it. That class is poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: can I use 1 formatter on Server side to handle both date value..

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

Your two formats are:

1. `date1` is ISO 8601 format. Both of `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime` parse this format as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter.
2. `date2` is RFC 1123. A formatter for this format is built in. To make sure we pick up all the information from the string in this format, we should parse into `OffsetDateTime`.

> I am trying to write if else block …

The two formats different enough that a simple `if` condition should be able to distinguish. For example:

```
public static OffsetDateTime parseTwoFormats(String dateStr) {
    if (Character.isLetter(dateStr.charAt(0))) {
        // Seems to begin with day of week; try RFC 1123
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(dateStr, DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
    } else {
        // Try ISO 8601
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(dateStr);
    }
}
```

Try it out with your two example strings:

```
    String date1 ="2011-08-31T18:30:00Z";
    String date2 ="Thu, 01 Sep 2011 00:00:00 GMT";

    OffsetDateTime odt1 = parseTwoFormats(date1);
    OffsetDateTime odt2 = parseTwoFormats(date2);

    System.out.println("odt1: " + odt1);
    System.out.println("odt2: " + odt2);
```

Output is:

> ```
> odt1: 2011-08-31T18:30Z
> odt2: 2011-09-01T00:00Z
> ```

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution,  but setting value in catch block is something I am avoiding.I am trying to write if else block in try ..based on the type of date format my date formatter code executes but not getting how to get Date patter.